# Auto-flushing Play! logs into logs/system.out

Tags: logging, log4j, playframework

I noticed that Play! logs don't always flush immediately after calling log4j's `logger.log()`.

I created a `log4j.properties` file in the `conf` folder, set the root logger to `INFO`, and am using log4j for printing logs.

I have one action that always emits a log message, yet I need to call it twice before I see anything in the log file - and after I call it twice I see two log lines.

The conclusion is that output redirection into logs/system.out is not automatically flushed.

Is there a configuration that will make Play! auto-flush the logs after each write?

Answer (score 0):

Play logger doesn't cache anything. So it's a problem of log4j. If you use a file logger you can define the buffer-size and force log4j to write directly.

Comment: I'm currently using a console logger, that Play redirects to a file.